# rotate animation in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-animation

i'm creating a wheel rotating animation which will automatically run when i run the app...i want it to rotate 90 degrees and pause a while then rotate 90 degrees again until it reach 360%...here's my code::

```
public void Start(){
    RotateAnimation counterSpinW = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, 50,50);
    counterSpinW.setRepeatMode(1);
    counterSpinW.getFillAfter();
    counterSpinW.setDuration(8000);

    counterSpinW.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   bigLayout.startAnimation(counterSpinW);

   RotateAnimation counterSpinW2 = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, 50,50);
   counterSpinW2.setRepeatMode(1);
   counterSpinW2.getFillAfter();
   counterSpinW2.setDuration(8000);
   counterSpinW2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  bigLayout.startAnimation(counterSpinW2);

  RotateAnimation counterSpinW3 = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, 50,50);
  counterSpinW3.setRepeatMode(1);
  counterSpinW3.getFillAfter();
  counterSpinW3.setDuration(8000);
  counterSpinW3.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
 bigLayout.startAnimation(counterSpinW3);

 RotateAnimation counterSpinW4 = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, 50,50);
 counterSpinW4.setRepeatMode(-1);
 counterSpinW4.getFillAfter();
 counterSpinW4.setDuration(8000);
 counterSpinW4.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
bigLayout.startAnimation(counterSpinW4);
```

i think maybe this won't work..but i never tested it yet....

Comment: with all my respect i think that using xml for annimation is better than hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [setStartOffset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset%28long%29)

```
firstRotateAnimation.setStartOffset(0);
pauseAnimation.setStartOffset(8000);
newRotateAnimation.setStartOffset(16000);
```